# Ionic Angular NgModel error reference a subobject in interface

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

This is my interface:

booking.interface.ts

```
export interface Booking {
  "dateBooking": Date;
  "period": {
    "morning": boolean;
    "afternoon": boolean;
    "night": boolean;
  }
}
```

addbooking.ts

```
...
import { Booking } from '../../models/booking/booking.interface';
...
export class AddbookingPage {

  //declare a property of interface type
  public booking = {} as Booking;

   constructor() {
  }
...
```

When I try to reference booking.period.morning in the view or any sub property o my object period, Ionic raise a error:

addbooking.html

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Morning</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="booking.period.morning"></ion-checkbox> 
  </ion-item>
```

Error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_co.booking.period.morning')
```

I trying to implement a checkbox and save the data in Firebase. I accept suggestions if there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: use class instead of interface

Comment: `public booking` is an empty object, `as Booking` only tells Typescript, that it should intercept `{}` as `Booking` type.

Comment: you can use safe navigation operator in your html if you are initializing later on

Answer (score 0):

You need to either:

initialize your object to match your interface

```
public booking: Booking = {
  dateBooking: new Date(),
  period: {
   morning: true,
   afternoon: false,
   night: false, 
  }  
}
```

or hide the checkbox until the object has the `period.morning` property.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Morning</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox *ngIf="booking && booking.period && typeof booking.period.morning === 'boolean'" [(ngModel)]="booking.period.morning"></ion-checkbox> 
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Thanks. It solve my problem. I don't know was necessary to initialise the object.

Comment: Glad I could help. Can you upvote and accept my answer? :)

Comment: I tried but: ˜Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.˜